# How to fix increasing Scrollbar thumb size while scroll of a div in iPad

Tags: html, ipad, css

The scroll-bar thumb size keeps increasing when I scroll a 'overflow-y:scroll' div in iPad. Any idea how to fix this design break??

```
position: absolute;
max-height: 200px; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
overflow-x: hidden;
```

The above is the basic style set for the element.

This is how it looks in iPad as scrolled to almost bottom of the div.
[image]

This is the expected behaviour :
[image]

Comment: position: absolute;
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: the above is the basic style set for the element.

Comment: @user3513687 Are you using custom scrollbar? Can you make an example in jsFiddle? Question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use native scrolling with: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

[Safari Developer Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW26)

I tried to reproduce this behaviour with the ipad simulator http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kApKB

The problem could also be the variable height.